# How to avoid race condition when using Process.Exited

Tags: c#, windows, process

I would like to write a method that waits for a process to die and then perform some Action. My first draft below has a race condition wherein, if the process has exited after I check the `Exited` event, my Action will never execute. What is the most eloquent way to rewrite this method so it will be correct?

```
private void MonitorProcess(int processId, Action doOnExit)
    {
        Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);

        if (process.HasExited)
        {
            doOnExit();
        }
        else
        {
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.Exited += delegate { doOnExit(); };    
        }            
    }
```

Comment: You've got an entirely different race than you think.  GetProcessById() might return null or the entirely wrong process.  You'll need to rejigger this so you get the *processId* while you've got a handled opened on the process so Windows keeps the internal process object alive.

Comment: @HansPassant You are correct! I figured out that I need to use a combination of processID+processCreationTime to have a unique identifier of a process over time, and used that instead to check if the process exited or not.

Answer (score 2):

Attach the event handler first, then check if it has exited. In addition, guard against double invocation of your handler (you need to synchronize here because the Exit event might be fired concurrently with the 2nd check).

Using Reflector I get the impression that `Exit` fires immediately if the process has already exited. So there might not even *be* a race condition. I could not find confirmation in the docs, though.